# How to handle Cypress timeout errors for API calls

Tags: reactjs, async-await, ui-automation, cypress

I have button, it opens a side panel on click. On willMount of side panel, we fire an api to get data to be shown on panel. So, While api cal is in process , we are showing loader and then Shows a form with loaded data on success.

```
componentWillMount() {
const objReq = getObjectDetails(pathname,id); // fetch API
this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
  if (objReq && objReq[0]) {
    objReq[0].then((data) => {
      const objData = data.data[0];
      if (objData) {
        this.setState({loading: false });
        this.populateData(objData, objReq[1]); //function to populate data
      }
    });
  }
});
this.setState({ loading: false });
}
```

On Form, I have input field with pre-populated data. To test using, cypress I'm using below code.

```
describe('Page Tests', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
cy.server();
cy.route('GET', '{baseurl}/sdetails/*', sDetailmockDatadata).as('getSDetail');
});
describe('Test Create Form', () => { 
 beforeEach(() => {
        cy.wait('@getSDetail');
        cy.get('#sidePanelbTn').click({force:true});   // function to open side panel
      });
      describe('When Form submit button is Clicked', () => {
        it('Should show create form with pre-filled details of object', () => {
          cy.get('#firstInputBox').invoke('val').then((value) => expect(value).to.not.equal(''));
        });
      });
    })
})
```

In above test-case, we are checking for  value in firstInputBox, but when I run test in browser, it is showing loading screen and gets timeout saying 'timeout error : firstInputBox is not found'.

Though API is stubbed, and response is available, loader screen does not go away because of which firstInputBox id is not found in DOM.

Please help me in handling this scenarios.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be impossible. Cypress is a quite rough library.

> You cannot add a .catch error handler to a failed command.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Commands-Are-Not-Promises